# if statement doesn't work with function

Tags: c++, function, if-statement

```
void skaitoInformacija(){
    ifstream duomenys("duom.txt");
    int eil_nr;
    duomenys >> eil_nr;
    string eil[eil_nr];

    string nereikalinga_eilute;
    getline(duomenys, nereikalinga_eilute);

    for(int i=0; i<eil_nr; i++){
        getline(duomenys, eil[i]);
        if(salinamTarpus(eil[i]) == "good"){ //this if statement doesn't work

        }
    }
}

void salinamTarpus(string eil) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is nearly the least informative possible description. Please tell us *how* it doesn't work. If you got an error message from your compiler, please include the message (copy-and-paste it) in your question.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: ***Ask a question***, (*please*).

Comment: `void salinamTarpus(string eil)` returns `void` not string!! So that can't work!

Answer (score 3):

```
void salinamTarpus(string eil)
```

your function is not returning anything that you can compare with "good" string

you need to change it to return at least some result if you want to compare it...

```
string salinamTarpus(string eil) {
    if(eil == "okString")   // string eil is the right one
    {
        return "good";
    }
    return "bad";
}
```

also if your function `salinamTarpus(string eil)` returns only 2 values("good","bad") it might be better idea to return boolean,char or so. string is a little bit too much overkill

Comment: Put a compilable code sample please ...

Comment: Edited to hopefully match criteria. Pardon me still new to this.